# T4 Template C# - Keep regular string with \n \r .. in the generated code

Tags: c#, t4

I'm using T4 (C#) to generate some code at run-time. Then I stored the generated code in a string that is part of another Template. The relevant code in the final template looks like that :

```
string myFinalString = @"<#=GetGeneratedCode()#>";
```

where `GetGeneratedCode()` is :

```
public string GetGeneratedCode()
{
  MyTemplate temp = new MyTemplate (); //<- another T4 template
  return temp.TransformText();
}
```

`MyTemplate.TransformText` returns a code similar to the following :

```
MyClass
{
 int myVar1;
 string myVar2;
}
```

The problem is that in my generated source file, the string `myFinalString` is set has follow :

```
string myFinalString = @"MyClass
{
   int myVar1;
   string myVar2;
}";
```

I would prefer, for readability, get a generated regular string as follow :

```
string myFinalString = @"MyClass\r\n{\r\n int myVar1;\r\n string myVar2;\r\n}";
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: @GrantWinney It works, thanks.TransformText returns a string.  I did not think it was so simple... Could you please repost your comment as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping the `\r` and `\n` characters should work. Try this:

```
public string GetGeneratedCode()
{
  MyTemplate temp = new MyTemplate (); //<- another T4 template
  return temp.TransformText().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "\\r\\n");
}
```

Using the verbatim symbol works as well: `@"\r\n"`